# Pascal. Рекурсия. Сумма элементов массива

Tags: массивы, рекурсия, freepascal

подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли написать рекурсивную функцию, которая принимает один параметр, одномерный массив чисел и возвращает сумму чисел массива

```
function Sum(nums:array of integer):integer;
```

Не могу придумать, как это сделать с помощью одного параметра

Comment: 1. Да, возможно. 2. Наверняка уже есть готовая. 3. Не можете придумать, как сделать с помощью одного параметра, а с помощью двух можете?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
3. Да, доп. параметр будет проходить по массиву до окончания. 
Не могу найти как передать меньший массив в функцию :с

Comment: Что означает фраза "доп. параметр будет проходить по массиву"?

Comment: Вводим в функцию ещё один параметр i, который будет рекурсивно увеличиваться пока не найдем базовый случай

Comment: и зачем вам передевать этот параметр снаружи, когда его спокойно можно создать внутри самой функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсивную функцию можно организовать по-разному. Вы можете сперва что-то делать и передавать результат дальше по рекурсии, а можете сперва получать результат из рекурсивного вызова, а потом что-то с ним делать.

Как я понял, вы смогли реализовать первый вариант. Второй не потребует дополнительного параметра. Сначала забуритесь на максимальную глубину, а потом поднимайтесь вверх и складывайте. Вам потребуется способ разделить массив на первое значение -- голову и все остальные -- хвост.

1. Напишите код для пустого массива, он вернёт 0;
2. Если элементов 1 и больше, то разделите массив на голову и хвост: голова -- первое значение, хвост -- массив всего, что осталось;
3. Передайте хвост по рекурсии;
4. Верните сумму результата рекурсивного вызова и головы.

Comment: Здравствуйте, смог реализовать только с помощью ещё одного массива, который будет динамическим и будет создаваться на один элемент меньше и передаваться далее. 1. Правильно ли я решил? 2. Можно ли как-то обойтись без дополнительного массива? Спасибо!

Comment: @Taurinz алгоритм вы реализовали правильно. Но создание массивов будет приводить к неэффективному использованию памяти. Я не силён в паскале и не знаю какие конкретно есть средства для оптимизации в таком случае, но идея такая: вы можете работать не с массивом а со срезом -- типом, который является указателем на массив и границами от/до.  В таком случае данные копироваться не будут, но аргумент рекурсивной функции будет типа срез.

Comment: @Taurinz Если бы это был код для практического применения, то можно было написать функцию-обёртку, которая принимает массив, делает на основе него срез и запускает рекурсивную функцию для среза. А для целей изучения рекурсии важнее понять сам принцип организации рекурсии, а оптимизацией можно не заниматься.

Comment: Думаю что я её понял, просто для меня самого это было очень интересно, я сразу понял что расход памяти будет неэффективным, поэтому думал над "оптимизацией". Огромное вам спасибо!